# Unable to display text from stored procedure to textview - Android SQL Server

Tags: java, android, sql-server, stored-procedures

My issue is I have created a stored procedure to retrieve the max value from a table and I want to display this in my textview. But this doesn't seem to work. No errors are shown in the logs.

Notes:

- I have tested my stored procedure and it works fine.
- This is a fragment, not an activity (don't know if that's the issue)

Below are my codes:

In the `onCreate` method - trying to retrieve the max value which contains only 1 column

```
txtMaxValue.findViewById(R.id.txtMaxValues);

try {
    if (con != null) {
        String query = "exec dbo.RetrieveMaxValue";
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            txtMaxValue.setText(resultSet.getString(1));
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger. Step through your code line-by-line. Presumably the WHILE statement finds nothing and returns FALSE. Is that correct?

Comment: Is `con` initialized?

Comment: @SMor well when I execute the stored procedure, it does return something and there is only one column.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what your table is like in SQL Server, but I think instead of one you should put zero or write the name of the column.
You can also get values by creating a list of numbers and then displaying them
Do not forget that with debugging you can check for the first step whether the data is called from the database or not.